# How do I unregister or assume an existing registration with the liblinphone sdk

Tags: ios, linphone-sdk

On iOS when someone kills the app there is no time to unregister, next time the app runs I want to either unregister or assume the existing registration. It appears like every time you register liblinphone generates a new UUID in the contact. Thus the registrations will stack up every time they kill the app.

I removed the UUID from the contact `mCore.config?.setString(section: "misc", key: "uuid", value: "0")` which allowed it to assume the registrations but that broke push notifications.

Ideally I would like to be able specify the UUID for a liblinphone registration so I can re-use it but even just being able to unregister the previous registration would work

Answer (score 0):

```
 mCore.config?.setString(section: "misc", key: "uuid", value: "E3021C23-149E-4C90-998A-736B1718C252")
```

Apparently it was an easy fix, I thought 0 was to disable it but looking through the liblinphone source code that is actually how you set the ID. So you can generate you own id and make it the same and it will assume the registration.